# How did NPM create the border for their update message?

Tags: unicode, npm, terminal

I'm assuming they used unicode characters to render the yellow box around the update message.

What characters were used and does it look the same on all platforms?

[image: NPM update dialog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How did NPM create the border for their update message?

NPM uses [`npmlog`](https://github.com/npm/npmlog) to print to the console, and `npmlog` utilizes [`console-control-strings`](https://github.com/iarna/console-control-strings) & [`gauge`](https://npmjs.com/packages/gauge).

- `console-control-strings` mostly offers convenience functions for moving the cursor around the line and coloring the text.
- `gauge` provides the progress bar and spinner and a way to style them.

> What characters were used and does it look the same on all platforms?

[Unicode box-drawing characters](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/2500-257F) are used for the border characters. I didn't research the exact unicode characters that NPM uses. Assuming that the terminal/platform is implemented to support unicode and, doesn't override the standard charset with its own characters (ie. emojis), I don't see why it wouldn't look the same across platform.

The below snippet unicode characters don't match exactly. Instead, it demonstrates how to use `control-control-strings` to print something close to what NPM outputs. I'm sure with enough tinkering you could get it to be exact.

```
const control = require('console-control-strings')

let title = `${control.color('cyan')}Update available 5.0.3 \u2192 5.0.4${control.color('reset')}`
let subtitle = `Run ${control.color('cyan')} npm i -g npm ${control.color('reset')}`
let borderWidth = (title.length > subtitle.length ? title.length : subtitle.length)

let topLeftCorner = '\u256D'
let topRightCorner = '\u256E'
let btmRightCorner = '\u256F'
let btmLeftCorner = '\u2570'

let border = [...Array(borderWidth)].map(() => { return '\u2500' }).join('')
let topBorder = `${control.nextLine()}${control.color('yellow')}${topLeftCorner}${border}${topRightCorner}${control.color('reset')}`
let btmBorder = `${control.nextLine()}${control.color('yellow')}${btmLeftCorner}${border}${btmRightCorner}${control.color('reset')}`
let lineWrapper = `${control.color('yellow')}\u2502${control.color('reset')}`

console.log(topBorder)
console.log(`${lineWrapper}${control.forward(borderWidth)}${lineWrapper}`)
console.log(`${control.nextLine()}${lineWrapper}${control.forward(4)}${title}${control.forward(5)}${lineWrapper}`)
console.log(`${lineWrapper}${control.forward(11)}${subtitle}${control.forward(10)}${lineWrapper}`)
console.log(`${lineWrapper}${control.forward(borderWidth)}${lineWrapper}`)
console.log(`${btmBorder}${control.color('reset')}`)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is really in depth.